# Keep sentences with any word from the list python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
0         i only need uxy to hit 20 eod to make up for a...
1                                        oh this isn’t good
2         lads why is my account covered in more red ink...
3         i'm tempted to drop my last 800 into some stup...
4         the sell offs will continue until moral improves.
```

I have a list of words

```
names = ['is','account','will']
```

and I want to keep rows that match match any of the words from the list
Also, I want to remove rows if the spelling doesn't match the spelling from the list. For example if there is word accounts in the sentence I want to remove this row as well
I tried

```
words = [rf'\b{string}\b' for string in names]
df['found'] = df[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(words))]
```

Comment: The second problem can't be solved by any simple heuristic. Imagine there is the word "ellipsis" in the text and "is" in the word list: would you want to remove the row because "ellipsis" contains "is"?

Comment: I don't want any letters to surround these words only signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df['text].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: any([n in x for n in names]))]
```

Comment: return empty dataframe

Comment: Probably its the column location error. Try now

Comment: How to change it in a way that any sign can be around these words from the list but not letters

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: so is.!$ in the sentence would keep the whole row

Comment: sorry, I am not getting the question yet

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
# Print the output.
s = ['nick','krish']
for individual in s:
    if (individual in df.values):
        df.drop(df.loc[df['Name']==individual].index,inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: How to change it in a way that any sign can be around these words from the list but not letters. For example 
so is.!$ in the sentence would keep the whole row